# CSS inheritance (same style for div and div a)

Tags: css, inheritance, css-selectors

Is there a way to make that normal text and links share the same style in CSS ?

Please find below an example :

```
div.test, div.test a
{
font-size:0.8em;
}
```

I would like text and links to get the same style but it is not working as expected...

Any help welcome.

Cheers.

Gotye.

Comment: Well, what *does* it do?

Comment: Is the a tag nested within the div with class test? Have you tried changing the font-size value to ensure that it works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just specify

```
div.test
{
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

Otherwise you are telling links inside `div.test` to have 80% font size of `div.test`, which in turn is 80% of whatever its parent is. That's 64% the font size of `div.test`'s parent, so it appears smaller.

If you're trying to give normal text and link text the same color, or other properties that don't depend on relative sizing, use `div.test, div.test a` as you're doing but place it in a separate rule. For example:

```
div.test
{
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

div.test, div.test a
{
    color: #330;
}
```